# .htaccess redirect root directory and subpages with parameters

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd

I am having difficulty trying to redirect a root directory while at the same time redirect pages in a sub directory to a different URL. For example:

```
http://test.example.com/olddir/sub/page.php?v=one
```

to

```
http://test.example.com/new/one
```

while also redirecting the any request to the root of the olddir folder.

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v=one
RewriteRule ^/olddir/sub/page.php /new/? [R=301]
```

and

```
RedirectMatch /oldir "test.example.com"
RedirectMatch /olddir/sub/page.php?v=one "test.example.com/new/one"
```

Any help at this point will be extremely appreciated...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. I tips is to enable [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) to troubleshoot these things.

You could try something like this, and I assume you use `mod_rewrite 2.2`:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v=(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^/olddir/sub/page\.php /new/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Hope it helps you forward.